# How to compare login data on NodeJS with the registered users in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I just need to know how to compare email/password in MongoDB whenever a user `login` tries to log in. `If the user enters wrong crediantals` it should give `an Invalid pass/email`
I just want an idea of how to compare values. Your little time can save my day

```
function login() {
app.post('/login/', async(req, res) => {
const query = new Model({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });       
});
}

//here's the Schema and Mongoose Connection

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Login", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('connected mfs'))
    .catch((err) => console.error("error found...", err));

const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});

//connection
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening to port ${port}`));

//here's the headers

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend: true }));
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

Answer (score 0):

First import bcrypt.
and do the below code in your login function

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
let user = await model.findOneUser({ email: this.req.body.email});
if (user == null) {
    return sendResponse(this.res, 400, FAILED_MSG, 'Incorrect id or password.');
}

let isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(this.req.body.password, user.password);
if (!isValidPassword) {
    return sendResponse(this.res, 400, FAILED_MSG, 'Incorrect id or password.');
}
// do success code
```

Comment: i get this error on posting

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`
or this
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: model is not defined`

Comment: model = "your login schema".    use "async" key  word before your function like "async function login()".     and use "body parser" for req.body.

Comment: email me for further help